# How to load markers as they are seen in the view port (Google Map's API)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For my Google Maps API project, there are too many markers to have all of them loaded at once, so I first place a region marker in each state with a count of the existing markers as it's label.

I'm trying to create a process where if the user is at a certain zoom level, and the state's marker is in the view port, then load all the markers within the state.

Currently, however, I cannot get the process to work more than once. Here's the process below:

I've tried attaching the function below to a Google Maps event, such as the idle event or tilesloaded event, but I've decided to try and get the process working with the following:

```
var processingRequest = false;

    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (processingRequest == false) {
            markerZoomTrigger();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Note the variable processingRequest, this is used so the markerZoomTrigger function only runs once the previous request has finished. I did this in an attempt to solve the bug I'm having.

Here's the markerZoomTrigger function:

```
       function markerZoomTrigger() {

        console.log("Marker zoom triggered!");

        if (geoLocMap.getMap().getZoom() < 8) {
            console.log("Zoom is less than 8");
            return;
        }


        var count = 0;
        //Gives us markers in window
        //TODO
        /*
         If zoom level is x, then getDetailedInfo for each marker in region. mailingID == 0 means its a region marker
         */
        var markers = geoLocMap.getRegionMarkers();

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (geoLocMap.getMap().getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {

                var zoomLevel = geoLocMap.getMap().getZoom();

                console.log("[" + count + "] Marker " + markers[i].getPosition() + " is in the selection");
                console.log("[" + count + "] is region marker: " + markers[i].isRegionMarker);
                console.log("[" + count + "] Zoom level: " + zoomLevel);

                if (typeof markers[i] == 'undefined' || typeof markers[i].state == 'undefined') {
                    console.log("Marker found with undefined state property");
                    continue;
                }

                //Make sure the marker is a region marker, and it hasn't been generated
                if (markers[i].isRegionMarker == true && markers[i].generated == false) {
                    console.log("Marking processingRequest as true...");
                    processingRequest = true;

                    if (typeof markers[i].state == 'undefined') {
                        console.log("Marker passed to httpPostCoordCount is undefined");
                        continue;
                    }

                    httpPostCoordCount(markers[i].state);
                    document.getElementById("load").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    geoLocMap.setGeneratedMarker(markers[i], true);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Just as some background, `geoLocMap` is a class I created to house the map and other project-specific data. Any references to `regionMarker` is the marker I discussed in the first paragraph. Lastly, `httpPostCoordCount` is an AJAX request to retrieve the markers of a given state, as seen here:

```
function httpPostCoordCount(state) {

        $.post(postRequestCoordCountURL,
            {
                state: state,
                debug: debug
            },
            function (data, status) {
                console.log("Status of Coord Count Post: " + status);

                //Adds markers from request JSON
                addMarkersToMap(JSON.parse(data), state);

                console.log("Marking processingRequest as false...");
                processingRequest = false;
            });
    }
```

Currently, after a state's markers are successfully loaded once, the console message "Marker zoom triggered!" is continuously printed, with no other messages.

Comment: We would need a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to tell what is going on. But are you sure this is the best way to accomplish what you want? What happens if the zoom level is reached, you are over a certain state but the state marker isn't within the viewport? Nothing shows?

Comment: I'd suggest you to have a look at [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering). What you could also do is to listen to the `bounds_changed` event (which reacts to zoom and pan changes) and to make an async call to your database to only return markers within the bounds. I did that for a project where I have a huge amount of markers to display, combined with a min. zoom level, and this works great.